# Are there any kid sized alpine touring ski boots and bindings?

Tags: boots, children, alpine-touring

Do any kid size (205 mm or 32 EU) ski touring boots and bindings exist? The smallest size I'm able to find is 220 mm, 35 EU.

Comment: This is not price-shopping, this is a perfectly reasonable question whether there is a specific piece of equipment on the market. Yes, a specific recommendation might disappear from the market in time, but hardly very quickly and even if, it still is a pointer for where to search in the future. And price isn't mentioned once.

Comment: I think Hagan goes down to a mondo 21 with their junior binding however you have to be careful which boot you use. Silvretta  Pure or Naxo bindings are some commonly modified to get to the size needed. If you belong to a good club some already modified often get passed to someone else's kids when outgrown.(din on modified will stay about 3 so not the most for child safety)  I think that because of the kind of modification involved the writeup would me more for a forum setting than SE since depending on boots there might be different adjustment/mods to be explained

Comment: Many just opt for a crosscountry set and carry their kids downhill set when needed. There are also some touring adapters that some like and some dont.

Comment: @Sue, for those particular things its a very weird market, any suggestion given in one answer would easily work for one season and not for the next. OP would be better served to ask in local ski clubs and shops or post the question in forums where he will find guides and continuous help if he needs to go DIY.It would be impossible here to explain how to modify a whole list of bindings (new-ish or old), to list which bindings cant be modified easily, etc to give a complete answer and if older gear is listed OP might end with bindings that dont fit newer boots

Comment: @Erik vanDoren, unfortunately I don't belong to any clubs so I don't have where to ask. Also I have checked a shops and they don't sell such small size equipment. That's why I'm looking for answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. There is adapter for kids. It's possible to use this adapter with usual skis.[image]

Here is the link with more description:
https://www.camp-usa.com/product/brands/contour-skins/contour-startup-ski-touring-adapter/

And here is a video on youtube how the adapter works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8Exg3U56ZQ

Answer (score 1):

the adapter is heavy as is the entire setup (downhilll skis+bindings+adapter+boots), if you want to take your kids out to backcountry for more than 30-60 minutes, this will be very heavy for them... Instead, take an old pair of downhill skis, rivet the climbing skins to them... attach cross-country binding and put them in cross-country ski boots. Put the downhill skis + boots in your backpack....

[this is Adam at the age of 5, about 6 miles/4000 ft climb](https://www.facebook.com/pethorvath/videos/10210430309905757/?l=7123596541458548389)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's a bit to late. I have already tied it with my daughter. We have tried it for 6-8 hour of walking per day. And we have tried it for few days. I agree that adapter is super heavy. It's also increasing skies hight so a kid has less stability.